# Can I make network calls within my iOS background fetch?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am currently trying to create notifications when a user has new messages. I'm trying to do this with local notifications because I'm very much a beginner and it seems(?) easier than push notifications. My question is, can I check my Firebase database during my background fetch?

What I've experienced is that the background fetch function works- but only before my app memory has been suspended, thus negating the point of the background fetch. I run it, I simulate a background fetch, but unless the app was just open, it does nothing and tells me "`Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.`"

Here's my code if it's useful. I know it probably seems like a funky way to go about this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        //there was other firebase stuff here that I don't think is relevant to this question

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (didAllow, error) in

        }

        UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        myDatabase.child("users").child(userID!).child("hasNewMessages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value as! Bool == true {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "You have unread messages"
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing", content: content, trigger: trigger)

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats a very bad idea. User push notifications from firebase. Its easy. Open firebase docs and read about remote notifications. Also in this doc you can find complete AppDelegate files for receive notifications. And you can't doing code in background. You can do something on didBecomeActive.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to look at using push notifications as then your user's don't have to wait until iOS decides to invoke your background fetch; they can be notified of new messages immediately.

However, your problem is as described by the message you see in the console; you need to invoke the `completionHandler` that was passed to the background fetch method when you have finished your background operation to let iOS know what happened.  It uses this information to tune how often and when your background fetch method is called.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    myDatabase.child("users").child(userID!).child("hasNewMessages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.value as! Bool == true {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "You have unread messages"
            content.badge = 1

            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing", content: content, trigger: trigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it only give me the error when it didn't run the main fetch function? Wouldn't the completion handler not be called anytime, whether or not memory had been suspended?

Comment: Yes, your code was wrong in all instances, but unless your app has just been running you probably don't have a debugger connection to see the error message. The background fetch was being executed, but because you didn't call the completion handler, ios didn't get feedback on what happened so you will find that your background fetch is not called very often.